# Best practice when creating authorization tokens and what they can access

Tags: security, authorization

Consider the following:

1. Login to a secure web site.
2. When logged in, show a link to another more secured page.
3. When logged in, show button "Erase All".

On one hand, you can create an authorization token T1 for accessing item 1, another token T2 to access item 2 and token T3 to access item 3. This means that if a user wants to be able to do all three, the user must have all three tokens (T1, T2, T3).

On the other side, you can create an authorization token T1 for item 1. Then you can create token T2 which allows you to do both item 1 and item 2. Token T3 allows you to do all three items. This means that a user only have to have token T3 to do all three.

What is best practice when designing the authorization tokens and what they can access?

Comment: Please add more details to the question, for ex: whether you are planning to use OAuth2.0 or OAuth? When you say more secured page, whether the page is part of one single web application or a different application? Is there a Single Sign-on server that already exists for you to use or if you are open to new ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about best practice, but to me it seems you'll have better luck implementing authorization tokens if you can provide your use cases more clearly.

Additionally you could use OAuth2.0 to help ease the security implementation. Specifically with OAuth2.0 you can have a common authentication provider to prove identity, and then based on the identity token swap it with your apps for an Authorization Token that is specific to that user's identity.

This way a user would only have to login to one provider and through OAuth automatically obtain authorization for apps that they are white listed on.

Comment: Maybe my question was a bit vague, sorry about that :). The question is more of a design principle than how to do the implementation. For example, if we take an authorization token (access token or just an access flag). You can design the system so this flag opens the "door" to function 1, or design that it opens several doors (to function 1, 2 and 3). If you choose the first case, then you have to have a second flag to open door 2 and a third flag to open door 3. So, in the first case the user have to have three flags to open all doors. In the second case the user has to have only one flag.

Comment: Is it "better" to have one flag for each function or have one flag to "rule them all", so to speak :)

Comment: It is better to be discrete, and not collective.

Comment: I agree. I think that it is easier to do the configuration and coding if you choose the discrete way. On the other hand, it is easier for the end user the collective way. Instead of ordering a bunch of "flags" he/she can order just one.